# How many rabbis are in the Talmud?

Tags: talmud-gemara, rabbis

I am looking for an actual count of rabbis mentioned by name in the Talmud/Midrash Rabbah/Zohar.  I recall reading "more than 1,000" somewhere.  Has anybody produced a count?

Comment: At least regarding the Talmud and Mishnah, you may want to clarify "rabbi". Not everyone named received the title "rav", "rabban", etc. Numerous such examples - Hillel, Shamai, Elisha ben Avuya to name a few.

Comment: Start with this book: https://books.google.com/books?id=yZoixixkFkUC

Comment: And then [this](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Encyclopedia_of_Talmudic_Sages.html?id=rpbXAAAAMAAJ) one. Or before, whichever :)